# Returning two values from data layer in one variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm working with GTM and I wish to return two variables in a Data layer to my GTM variable.

When I try each of them separately, they work as expected. However, the problem is that I wish to combine them together.

These two works when I test them separately

```
function(){
  return Code = ecommerceData[0].Field.field1|| undefined;
}
```

And

```
function(){

  return ecommerceData[0].cart.fields[0].Name || undefined;
}
```

I have problem with combining them together and this one does not give me the results that I expect

```
function(){
  Code = ecommerceData[0].Field.field1;
  Name = ecommerceData[0].cart.fields[0].Name;
  return Code , "_" , Name|| undefined;
}
```

Any tips or guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: why don't you return an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement:

```
return Code , "_" , Name|| undefined;
```

returns the last value only, in your case it's "Name" variable. You can read more about comma separated values in return statement on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

So to solve your problem you can change it to an array for example:

```
return [Code , Name] || undefined;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could return an array with both values.